# How to make graduated symbology using ArcPy (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, point, symbology

I visualize a column named `cdir` (relating to dataset `test_points`) via Arcpy. Currently, this is done with the Unique Renderer Symbology:

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps('Map')[0]
layer = m.listLayers('test_points')[0]
cp = layer.connectionProperties
print(cp)
cp['connection_info']['database'] = arcpy.env.workspace
layer.updateConnectionProperties(layer.connectionProperties, cp)

sym = layer.symbology
sym.updateRenderer("UniqueValueRenderer")
sym.renderer.fields = ["cdir"]      # sets field

# Set up intervals based on the provided percentiles and statistics
intervals = [1350144, 1365084.8, 1396032.0, 1401856.0]

# applying symbology to each defined value
for grp in sym.renderer.groups:
    for itm in grp.items:
        myVal = float(itm.values[0][0])
        print("myVal: {0}".format(myVal))
            
        if myVal < intervals[0]:

            itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [190, 232, 255, 100]}        
            itm.symbol.size = 10
            itm.label = str(myVal)

        if myVal >= intervals[0] and myVal < intervals[1]:

            itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [255, 250, 22, 100]}        
            itm.symbol.size = 10
            itm.label = str(myVal)
 
            
        if myVal >= intervals[1] and myVal < intervals[2]:
            itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [255, 127, 0, 100]}        
            itm.symbol.size = 10
            itm.label = str(myVal)
            
            
        if myVal >= intervals[2] and myVal < intervals[3]:
            itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [255, 0, 0, 100]}        
            itm.symbol.size = 10
            itm.label = str(myVal)
            
        elif myVal >= intervals[3]:
            itm.symbol.color = {"RGB": [128, 0, 128, 100]}      
            itm.symbol.size = 10
            itm.label = str(myVal)


layer.symbology = sym
```

The symbology output is:

[image]

Rather, I would like to have the symbology visualized gradually, containing five different colored points with classes:

[1] <1350144,

[2] 1350144 - 1365084.8,

[3] 1365084.8 - 1396032.0,

[4] 1396032.0 - 1401856.0,

[5] >1401856.0

How to create the gradual symbology using Arcpy in a similar way as the example given in this question ("UniqueValueRenderer")?

Comment: Have you looked at CIM?  I suspect that may provide the functionality that you seek.

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to read if it excluded all the text and code that was irrelevant to the question.  Ie, everything up to and including the word "Lastly" is just unnecessary distraction.